# How to access Opportunity details from Contact

Tags: opportunity, contact

I have a Detail page button on the contact object on click of which I need to do some processing for which I need the Opportunity details. But when I access the merge fields on Opportunity, I get blank values.

Is there a way to fetch the Opportunity details from Contact on click of a custom page button?

Comment: Considering that Contact to Opportunity is a one to many relationship you would need to have a single opportunity defined on the Contact record before this would work. Do you have that lookup?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the OpportunityContactRole (OCR) on that Contact as being related to the Opportunity. See the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) and Salesforce Help for more on OCR.